# You do not have the permissionss necessary to view the contentss of "eclipse"

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I accidently entered below commands:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /home/shuvro/android-sdk-linux
sudo chmod -R +r /home/shuvro/android-sdk-linux
```

Arter running the commands, now I am unable to open eclipse.  Now what can I do?

Here android-sdk-linux is the folder where I put eclipse adt.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the ownership of the folder. Now it can be opened only by root, i.e. using sudo command. You need to change the permission to the user again. Just type:

```
chown -R <your user name> <path to the folder>
```

Also read some guides how to use chown and chmod commands. Here are two examples: [chown](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/) [chmod](http://catcode.com/teachmod/)

If you are a begginer in android programming, I'd recommend to start with [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) instead of Eclipse ADT, as Eclipse is out of further development.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am beginner in Android.