# Invalid Configuration Location

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

> The configuration area at '/home/shuvro/android-sdk-linux/eclipse/configuration' is not writable.  Please choose a writable location using the '-configuration' command line option

I am facing this error while trying to launch eclipse. How can I fix it? I have another question- How can I completely uninstall the Eclipse ADT bundle?

Comment: uninstalling eclipse is easy. Just delete the folder.

Comment: Judging from your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28053463/1639625), I guess that some folders are still owned by `root`. Why did you set the folder to `chown -R root:root` anyway?

Comment: Running the command was a mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can set the correct rights for this folder, as I suggest it is not owned by your user.

On the other hand you can launch your eclipse with the '-configuration' parameter as suggested in the errormessage. Using this parameter you can use any folder on your system where you are able to write.

Comment: "On the other hand you can launch your eclipse with the '-configuration' parameter"- please explain  this line.

Comment: launch your eclipse like this from a command-line:
`./eclipse -configuration /home/foo/some/configuration/folder`

Comment: You are late.I have reinstalled the whole adt. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I cme across this somewhere else on the web. This solved my issue instantly:

> REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Desktop" /t REG_SZ /d "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" /f

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on my **Windows** machine.
My C: drive was **corrupted**. It used to show **error 0x80070570**.

Its very easy to solve on windows, just right click the drive > properties > tools tab > under error checking click on the check button (give admin permissions) and reboot the system when asked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Eclipse and ADT on Windows. The solution was quite simple but hard to detect:

I ran the ADT update from within Eclipse and this downloaded several new Android system images to `<ADT install Folder>\sdk\system-images` More than 4 GB in total. This consumed all the free disk space and thus on next launch ADT could not write any more to `<ADT install Folder>...`

Not directly related to the question but still close enough to maybe be some help to others with the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

There was not enough space left, once i cleared some memory and started eclipse successfully.